# If and if isset problems

Tags: php

I can't solve problem in news editing. So, there's my code

```
if(!$_GET['id'])
{
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY id ASC");
    echo 'Edit<hr />';
    while($output = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
        echo $output['subject'].' &raquo; <a href="?id='.$output['id'].'">Edit</a><br />';
}
```

and, on site i get this:

> Notice: Undefined index: id in \htdocs\nadzorno_okolje\inc\allnews.php on line 28
>
> Notice: Undefined index: id in `\htdocs\nadzorno_okolje\inc\allnews.php` on line 28

Comment: What is the HTML that interacts with this bit of code, post that please.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. To highlight a code block, no need to use backticks. Instead, highlight it and `ctl-k` or click the `{}` editor toolbar button to indent it 4 spaces as a code block. Backtick enclosures may be used for inline code.

Comment: Have you tried if(!isset($_GET['id']) || $_GET['id'] == "") instead?

Comment: I am not sure if *Notice* message is for the *id* in `$_GET['id']` or `$output['id']`. Anyway try using `if (empty($_GET['id']))` instead

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing

```
if(!$_GET['id'])
{
}
```

You could use `empty`.  This will check to see if contains anything but also check to see if it's set first

```
if(empty($_GET['id']))
{
}
```

Comment: You would want `!empty()` in this case, but pointless with the OP's code as they aren't using `$_GET['id']`.

Comment: @AbraCadaver Sure I just need `empty()` because they are checking to see if it **doesn't** contain anything